# Linetype in legend is distorted

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot that shows the memory usage of some function over time, for two different versions of the function. Now, for each version I added a dashed regression line. So I added a legend (with `scale_linetype_manual`) which clarifies that solid lines represent the actual measurements and dashed lines represent the regression line. However, there is something wrong with the dashed line in the legend and I can't find out what is causing this:

[image: Problem with dashed item in legend.]

The problem is more clear when i use a dotted line for the regression line instead of a dashed line. Those smaller extra dots should not be in the legend:

[image: Problem with dotted item in legend.]

Here is the relevant part of my R script:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = heapUsage, color=Version)) +
  geom_line(aes(lty="data")) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', se=TRUE, aes(lty="trend")) +
  scale_linetype_manual("Data", values=c("solid", "dotted"), breaks=c("data", "trend"), labels=c(" Measured  ", " Regression line")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA))) +
  guides(linetype=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA, color="black"))) +
  labs(x = "# Executed Operations") +
  labs(y = "Heap Usage in MB")
```

And here is what the entire plot looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue arises from both `geom_line` and `geom_smooth` drawing a legend that gets overlayed.

You can switch off the legend for `geom_smooth` by adding `show.legend = FALSE`. Here is a reproducible example based on `mtcars`. If you omit `show.legend = FALSE` (or set `show.legend = TRUE`) you will see the overlay effect of the black and blue lines in the legend.

```
mtcars %>%
    select(mpg, disp, qsec) %>%
    gather(k, v, -mpg) %>%
    ggplot(aes(mpg, v, linetype = k)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = T, show.legend = F) + 
    geom_line() +
    scale_linetype_manual("Data", values=c("solid", "dotted")) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]